# How do I download an iPhone picture as the "Modified Original Photo" to my Mac while using "Optimize Photo Storage"?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, image-capture

My mom is a photographer, and she wants the original quality photos downloaded off her iPhone to use in professional photo programs like Lightroom and Photoshop.

She previously used `Image Capture` to do this, but has recently begun using `Optimize Photo Storage` to also store all these photos on iCloud.

According to [my research](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251663354), this means that sometimes photos downloaded via `Image Capture` will not be full size, so `Image Capture` is out.

We instead tried to download these originals via the `Photos app` on the Mac. However, you can only download the **unmodified** original photo (in `Image Capture` it showed the original AND the modified for download).

This is inconvenient of course because any edits made on the iPhone won't come through.

We also tried to export a JPEG from the `Photos app`, but both the `High` and `Maximum` quality were not the same size or quality as the modified original photos we could download on `Image Capture`. It seems a normal export via the `Photos app` does some kind of conversion on it so it is no longer original. But that also seems to be the only way to get the modifications from the `Photos app`

So...how do we download the **modified** original image from the `Photos app`?

(Or...how would we download the modified original image from `Image Capture` while guaranteed that the photo is the Full Size photo and not a thumbnail or some other not full quality version?)

Comment: Try the app [Camera+ 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/camera-2/id1313580627), or some non-Apple camera app which lets you save the file outside the Apple infrastructure. I can snap away into Camera+ 2's Lightbox, and then export the files I select in RAW format directly to Dropbox.  Camera+ 2 has so many pro features I can't think of using any other camera app. Unfortunately, it can't be set as the default camera app in iOS. Best US$8.00 I've ever spent. Solid updates and new features over the years. _Note: no financial or other consideration given by **LateNiteSoft S.L.**_

Comment: First, the optimized image size is very small and will look pixelated. If you're getting this photo, it would look terrible after importing to your computer. If you can't CLEARLY tell the difference then this isn't the problem.

Comment: Second, when you import from Image Capture are you getting JPEG or HEIC files? What about from iCloud.com. The JPEG files are not the original file format so it would make sense they don't match size wise.

Comment: Third, you can view the size of a photo on your phone. If you swipe up (or press the info button) you'll see a size in MB in the info panel. This is what you should be referencing when determining which size is most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Photos on Mac does let you export edited photos. Select photos, then in the top menu, click File > Export > Export N Photos'. If you export JPGs, Photos *will* apply some compression. For non-lossy transfers, you could set the iPhone to capture RAW format (See [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211965)). Lightroom can now also import directly from iPhone (See [this](https://www.theverge.com/2019/12/10/20999378/lightroom-ios-direct-import-photos-ipad-camera-roll)).

Comment: I've seen that Lightroom can import directly from the iPhone, but if Optimize Photo Storage is on wouldn't that leave something to be desired? How does Lightroom manage that?

Comment: If Optimize Storage is 'on', programs such as Lightroom (for Mac and iPhone) and Photos Takeout (for Mac) will download the full resolution unmodified originals from iCloud into your local Photo library, apply edits (if any), and then export.